# How do I disable my datapickers textbox, while allowing the user to still click the drop down button?

Tags: html, css

Quick issue here. I have run into a problem with my date selector in my booking form. As my date-selector has a min and max date, I do not want to give the user the opportunity to write whatever date he/she wants into the textbox field, so obviously this means it must be disabled. But by disabling the textbox, my datapicker is also disabled. Is there a cunning way around this?

**The date-picker code**

> ```
>                   <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" require="">
>                     <input name="new_booking_date" width="276"  placeholder="Date" class="form-control input-md" type="date" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+30 day")); ?>" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day")); ?>" required="" disabled
>                     <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></div>
>                   </div>
> ```

[image: Text-box enabled]
[image: Text-box disabled. Unable to access date-picker]/>

Comment: use `readonly` attribute for the `input` element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the readonly attribute:

```
<input readonly="readonly">
```

> If set to true, then the user cannot change the value of the element.
>   However, the value may still be modified by a script.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/readonly

By the way, the value for this attribute can be everything, including 'true' or even none, so this also would work:

```
<input readonly>
```

But it's better to use the W3C standard: readonly="readonly", as other options are invalid in HTML5 (except 'readonly' and the none option).